# Hartshorne Corollary 4.7, page 321

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having trouble understanding two statements from the proof of this Corollary.

First, we take a morphism of degree 2, say $\pi: X \to \mathbb P^1$ where $X$ is an elliptic curve sending our distinguished point to infinity, branched over $0,1,\lambda,\infty$. We consider $\sigma$ in the automorphism group $G$ of $X$, and we find an automorphism $\tau$ of $\mathbb P^1$ fixing infinity such that $\pi \circ \sigma = \tau \circ \pi$, so that $\tau$ permutes the branch points $0, 1, \lambda$.

Hartshorne then claims two things I do not follow:

1.) If $\tau$ is not the identity, $\lambda$, the cross ratio, must be equal to at least one of its other 5 orbit representatives under the action of permutation. Why is this the case?

2.) He then claims that if $\lambda$ equals exactly one other orbit representative, then the size of $G$ is $4$. Why is this true?

Comment: Regarding 1.): We know for a fact that $\tau$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ fixing $\infty$. I think one can check that such maps on $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{\infty\}$ are always scalar multiplication plus some shift (i.e. a linear transformation). This leads one to the hypotheses of Lemma 4.5. Now, we presume that $\tau$ isn't the identity so the permutation of $\{0,1,\lambda\}$ is nontrivial, excluding the first element in the orbit listed in Lemma 4.5.

Comment: Once you know that $\lambda = \text{(one of the five listed guys)}$, you solve for $\lambda$ and you consider the different cases. Leading to 2.), I guess the idea is as follows: For certain solutions of $\lambda$ you'll find that plugging in the six expressions in the list of Lemma 4.5 won't give six distinct numbers. For instance if $\lambda = -1$ the six representatives are in reality just four representatives.

Comment: At least, that's my take --- but take it with a slight grain of salt cause I didn't look into it well enough.

Comment: When he says lambda is one of the 5 listed guys, does he mean tau(lambda) instead?